# Converting pandas Dataframe with Numpy values to pysparkSQL.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I created a 2 columns pandas df with random.int method to generate a second two column dataframe applying groupby operations.
df.col1 is a series of lists, df.col2 a series of integers, and elements inside the list are *type 'numpy.int64'*, same for the elements of the second column, as result of random.int.

```
df.a        df.b
3            7
5            2
1            8
...

groupby operations 

df.col1        df.col2
[1,2,3...]    1
[2,5,6...]    2
[6,4,....]    3
...
```

When I try to crete the pyspark.sql dataframe with spark.createDataFrame(df), I get this error: 
TypeError: not supported type: type 'numpy.int64'.

Going back to the df generation, I tried different methods to convert the elements from numpy.int64 to python int, but none of theme worked:

```
np_list = np.random.randint(0,2500, size = (10000,2)).astype(IntegerType)
df = pd.DataFrame(np_list,columns = list('ab'), dtype = 'int')
```

I also tried to map with lambda x: int(x) or x.item() but the type still remains 'numpy.int64'.

According to pyspark.sql documentation, it should be possible to load a pandas dataframe, but it seems not compatible when it comes with numpy values. 
Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well the way how you do it doesn't work. If you have something like this. You will get the error because of the first column. Spark doesn't understand a list with the type numpy.int64

```
df.col1        df.col2
[1,2,3...]    1
[2,5,6...]    2
[6,4,....]    3
...
```

If you have something like this. The this should be okay.

```
df.a        df.b
3            7
5            2
1            8
```

In terms of your code, try this:

```
np_list = np.random.randint(0,2500, size = (10000,2))
df = pd.DataFrame(np_list,columns = list('ab'))
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

You don't really need to cast this as `int` again and if you want to do it explicitly, then it is `array.astype(int)`. Then just do `spark_df.head`. This should work!

Comment: Thanks @DatTran, that works. however the df I want to convert is the first one ( witch columns co1 and col2 and lists) not the second one; that's why I tried to force the conversion from 'numpy.int64' to 'python int' in the other dataframe.

Comment: @csbr again here... you need to accept those answer ppl provided you which solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

This is far from being a perfect solution, but this is what I actually run in production to get results:

```py
  for col_name in ['integer column', 'other int column']:
    df3[col_name] = pd.to_numeric(df3[col_name], downcast='integer').astype('Int64')

  def df_generator(df_in: pd.DataFrame) -> Generator[list, None, None]:
    # As PySpark won't accept numpy.Int64, do the stupid thing and iterate entire dataframe to
    # do any type conversion by ourselves.
    for row_idx, row in df_in.iterrows():
      row_out = []
      for data in row:
        if isinstance(data, str):
          row_out.append(data)
        elif data is None or data is pd.NA:
          row_out.append(None)
        else:
          row_out.append(int(data))
      yield row_out
          
  spark_df = spark_session.createDataFrame(df_generator(df3), schema=schema)
```

First I force imported data with known columns containing integers from strings into numbers and do another forcing of Int64 of them.

Then entire Pandas dataframe is converted into PySpark dataframe. It's a simple generator function to iterate entire Pandas dataframe (which is both discouraged and stupid) returning the exact same data as lists with proper data types.

I wish PySpark team would address this shortcoming to simplify working with Pandas-sourced data.