# how to convert a pandas dataframe contains numpy.ndarray elements into pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to save a pandas dataframe table contains numpy.ndarray into pyspark dataframe?

```
    data = [['tom', [1,2,3,4]], ['nick', [1,5,4,3]], ['juli', [1,2,4,3]]] 
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
```

I tired to do

```
    spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

which gives the error like this:

```
    TypeError: not supported type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I hope I could save this pandas df into a pyspark df. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411815/converting-pandas-dataframe-with-numpy-values-to-pysparksql-dataframe?rq=1

Comment: Convert it to a list. And you know what, your code only worked for me.